# Background loop doesn`t work properly in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Problem consist in incorrect background looping. Instead of scrolling the picture horizontally, it distort over time. This script correctly work with another material, but not with that one.

How it`s looks like (Right side is distorted):
[image]

I have this backgroundObject:

[image]

This background script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BackgroundLoop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bgSpeed;
    public Renderer bgRend;

    void Update()
    {
        bgRend.material.mainTextureOffset += new Vector2(bgSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the texture in the project window.
2. Then in the inspector window set `Wrap Mode` to `Repeat` (or `Mirror`)
3. Click Apply